# Why not just allocate a ton of memory?

Tags: c, memory

Recently, in C, I've been learning about dynamic memory location.

I also learned of the `limits.h` standard library.

When allocating memory, why not just do: `char array[INT_MAX]` instead of trying to make the memory all neat and perfect for what you are using it for?

I get that it is possible for there to not be enough memory available on the computer, but that could also happen when dynamically allocating memory.

Please include remarks about efficiency in your answer, please.

Here is an example piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[255];

    char str[INT_MAX];

    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if(fp) {
        while(fgets(255, buff, fp)) {
            strcat(str, buff);
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

This is an example of reading a file and putting all of it's contents into one string.

NOTE: This code was not compiled, so if there are any bugs, ignore them - I already explained what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: If you want to track all your memory usage yourself, by all means knock yourself out.

Comment: `char array[INT_MAX]` will allocate an array on the stack. The stack is usually only a few megabytes. `INT_MAX` is usually about 2 billion. Trying to allocate 2 GB on the stack is a good way to get a [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Also, manual memory management is a pain in the butt and, usually a waste of time. Also, most systems have hundred of process running at any given second, so if they all tried to allocate several GB of memory "instead of trying to make the memory all neat and perfect" you'd run out of memory fast. Can you perhaps clarify your question with an example?

Comment: @KerrekSB, I think the OP was suggesting allocating buffers for strings with the maximum number of characters, instead of trying to figure out what an appropriate maximimum size would be.  I don't think he was considering writing his own heap.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey: God knows. I can't second-guess the real question behind the question :-S

Comment: @Cornstalks afaik only nonstatic variables declared within a function are stored on the stack ...

Comment: @fvu: well, I was assuming `array` was a nonstatic variable declared within a function (`main()`, specifically), but sure, it could be a global. I guess it goes to show this question needs more context and clarification.

Comment: Because typically you would not *need* `INT_MAX` bytes. Allocating more than you have free physically may not work, or it may but move lots of stuff out of RAM into disk swaps, making everything on your system run slower. And all that because you can't guess a more reasonable size.

Comment: If you don't understand the likely magnitudes of the data involved in your problem, then you don't understand your problem well enough to begin programming. Programming is all about managing resources.

Comment: What if the file is more than `INT_MAX` bytes long?

Comment: @JohnBode The idea is to allocate a ton of memory, possibly an excess, for a task. `INT_MAX` was simply an example.

Comment: In certain life critical applications, `malloc()`, etc. are not allowed - neither are recursive function calls.  All memory usage is determined at start-up and static analysis determines max stack depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is as efficient as using a heavy truck to move a single small box... If you want to send a box or move your from your home, you almost all the time ask someone else to do it. And when you are hungry, I'm pretty sure that you never ask for all the food available at the restaurant.

Ok you can allocate as many memory as you can in one allocation, but now : how would you manage this huge chunk? You will certainly have needs such like using this part as an integer, this one to store a given structure, etc. And this will lead you to implement some kind of memory management by yourself. I'm sure that you wouldn't like to do so.

You also have to think about resource sharing, if you consume all is possibly available but more than what you need, some others will be in starvation.

Your scenario of putting in memory the whole content of a very very huge file is almost not realistic, there is almost no need for such a thing. Anyway, if you really need this you will probably use a memory mapped file not such a "reading-storing" algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of allocating the maximum buffer size for each string makes me think of a dinner party where the host doesn't know how much wine each guest will drink, so orders a barrel for each.  The dining hall is filled with barrels, and there's no room for anything else, including the guests.

Memory is a resource that must be managed so that you don't run out.  Or even if you don't run out, allocating more memory than you need can lead to slowing the system down due to swapping memory to disk to allow other applications to run.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about allocating one massive array and carving it up as necessary?  Or allocating multiple arrays of `INT_MAX` elements?

The main thing you're trying to avoid is internal fragmentation.  Suppose you want to store 100 strings, the longest of which will be 50 characters.  You could certainly just declare an array like

```
char strings[100][51]; // +1 for 0 terminator
```

and be done with it, but suppose you only have 1 string that's actually 50 characters long, and the rest are 5 characters long.  You wind up wasting 80% of the space you've allocated.  Whether that's a problem depends on what you're doing, but if nothing else it's inelegant.